# How to change custom validation rule file name laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, required, validationrules

I want to move all validation.php custom error messages to another file, so how do i change the default file name (`app/lang/en/validation.php`) to use custom filename. when i move the error message to another file, instead of the actual error message I get "`validation.required`" message
i found that the code resides in /Illuminate/Validation/Validate.php

```
function getMessage($attribute, $rule) {
     $key = "validation.{$lowerRule}";
}
```

i want to change the above code without touching the core file, can someone helpme please

Comment: Just put your custom rules in the $customMessages array (inside Model) and it will consider those while showing eror

Comment: I want to keep the error messages in language files

Comment: create the same $customMessages array in your validation.php, see if that works.

Comment: You may also want to use packages.

Comment: i want to remove validation.php file and rename it something else

Comment: why you want to that ?